# Pass Document credentials in C# Code

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am using following code to download SharePoint Document(Word) library and its working fine. However whenever i am trying to open this downloaded document, its keep asking document credentials.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("<Site URL>"))
                {
                    string filePath = @"Local Path";
                    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "Password", "domain");
                    context.RequestTimeout = 6600000;
                    Web web = context.Web;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("<Doc Library>");

                    ListItem listItem = list.GetItemById(1);
                    context.Load(listItem);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = listItem.File;
                    context.Load(file);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    var fileRef = file.ServerRelativeUrl;
                    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef);
                    var fileName = Path.Combine(filePath, (string)listItem.File.Name);
                    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                    {
                        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    }

}
```

Once I download the document, I am going to fetch content inside the documents with the help of "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application" API. Here I am getting all the content.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
ImpersonateUser iU = new ImpersonateUser();
iU.Impersonate("domain", "username", "Password");
doc = application.Documents.Open(@"LocalPath");
```

But each time its asking credentials. So would like to pass these credentials  through C# code?How to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you files are password protected. you need to open it by providing password.

```
Document newDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(@"C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\myNextFile.doc",
                                                              confirmConversions: false,
                                                              addToRecentFiles: false,
                                                              readOnly: false,
                                                              passwordDocument: "#$nonsense@!");
```

Comment: Yes,its password protect document.I used your code,but still its asking Credentials...

Comment: Please be more precise. Where it is asking password ? It is throwing exception in Code ?

Comment: Its not throwing any error.Whenever debugging point reaches the Documents.Open method,a window security pop up coming on screen and asking the protected document credentials.If i give my credentials(UserName,Password),its takes and moving to next line.

Comment: Please make sure the password you are providing here is correct. passwordDocument: "#$nonsense@!");

Comment: I hard coded correct password in the Documents.Open Method.

Comment: I've made a console application in VS2012, using .NET Framework 4.0 along with NetOffice.dll, v1.6. If I ommit the passwordDocument argument I get the password prompt dialog as well. If I add the passwordDocument argument then no dialog is shown and an exception is thrown.

Comment: DLL : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, IDE : VS 2013, Framework : 4.5 in Windows Application.